# Select records with mismatching referenced records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bit of a predicament with some bad data in Postgres. I have three tables, e.g., `family`, `genus`, and `audit_log_event`. A `family` can have many `genus`es, and `genus` has a foreign key reference to `family.id`.

`audit_log_event` has two foreign key columns: `family_id` and `genus_id`. Due to some buggy code making it to production, I now have `audit_log_event`s that reference a `genus_id` and `family_id`, but the `genus` referenced by `genus_id` references a different `family` than what is referenced by `family_id` on the same `audit_log_event`.

Put visually, I have data that looks like this:

[image]

I want to update the existing `audit_log_event`s to reference the `family` referenced by the `genus` referenced by each `audit_log_event`:

[image]

How can I select the `audit_log_event`s that reference different `family`s than their referenced `genus`es reference? Is there any way to perform an `UPDATE` query to let Postgres handle fixing the data, or would it be better to just select all the bad data and update it programatically outside of the database engine?

I tried the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
  a.genus_id as a_genus_id,
  a.family_id as a_family_id,
  a.id as audit_log_event_id
FROM genus g
JOIN audit_log_events a
  ON g.family_id = a.family_id AND a.genus_id != g.id
```

But this actually selects valid data and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around making a join select invalid data.

Comment: i do curious what have you tried?

Comment: I just added an example of something I tried

Comment: The problem stems for storing information redundantly. So, why not just drop the audit_log_events.family_id? Then the link to the family is implicit via genus.

Comment: We store the `family_id` for two reasons: audit log events that can apply to a `family` but not necessarily a `genus`, and performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not trust random query you found online outright, please test properly and evaluate**

You can do an `update` on a column with value taken from a `select` with `limit 1` on a single column as such:

```
update audit_log_event as al
    set family_id = (select family_id from genus as g
                     where g.id = al.genus_id limit 1);
```

The query above will update **every rows** to use the `family_id` referred by the `genus_id`. Hope it helps.

Also, normalizing the table would be very helpful in maintainability in the long run - though some may argue performance is worse or something.

See fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sddj65SkSvHjVoNsGjr5Jq/0

**EDIT:**

The following query should give you a preview of the records which will be affected:

```
SELECT
    id,
    family_id,
    genus_id
FROM
    audit_log_event AS al
WHERE
    family_id != (
        SELECT
            family_id
        FROM
            genus AS g
        WHERE
            g.id = a.genus_id)
```

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick. I'll evaluate more, of course. I edited the answer to add a query which should give a preview of the records that will be affected.

Thank you!